# How to make the first elemeny of my recycleview be open automatically when page loads in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want to make sure that the first element in the list is always toggled to open when the page loads. For reasons beyond me i have not been able to do it.

The recyclerview also holds a child recyclerview. I want to make sure the children of the first element of the parent recyclerview (which owns this adapter i am showing code for) is always visible when the page loads.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.xputer.table4two.Activity.BaseActivity
import com.xputer.table4two.Fragment.RestaurantPage
import com.xputer.table4two.Model.MenuCategory
import com.xputer.table4two.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.menu_category_list.view.*

class RestaurantMenuAdapter (val items: ArrayList<MenuCategory>, val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RestMenuViewHolder>() {
    private val viewPool = RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RestMenuViewHolder {
        return RestMenuViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.menu_category_list, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RestMenuViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val childLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(
            holder.recyclerView.context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
        childLayoutManager.initialPrefetchItemCount = items.size
        holder.recyclerView.apply {
            layoutManager = childLayoutManager
            adapter = menuSubCategoryAdapter(items[position].MenuSubCategories, context)
            setRecycledViewPool(viewPool)
        }

        holder.menuCatName.text = items[position].Name
        holder.recyclerView.visibility = View.GONE
        var expandNow = false
        holder.toggle.setOnClickListener {
            if (holder.recyclerView.visibility == View.GONE || expandNow) {
                if(items[position].MenuSubCategories.size == 0) {
                    ((context as BaseActivity).currentFragment as RestaurantPage).loadMenuSubCategory(items[position].Code) {
                        items[position].MenuSubCategories.addAll(it)
                        holder.recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        holder.toggleIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_up)
                    }
                }
                else{
                    holder.recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    holder.toggleIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_up)
                    expandNow = false
                }
            }
            else {
                holder.recyclerView.visibility = View.GONE
                holder.toggleIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_down)
                expandNow = false
            }
        }

//        if (items[0].MenuSubCategories != null) {
//            holder.recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
//            holder.toggleIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_up)
//            expandNow = true
//        }

        if (items[position].MenuSubCategories.find { i -> i.MenuItems.isNotEmpty() &&
                    i.MenuItems.find { j -> j.Deals.isNotEmpty() } != null
            } != null)
            holder.icon.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        else
            holder.icon.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}

class RestMenuViewHolder (view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    var recyclerView = view.menuSubCat
    var menuCatName = view.menuCatName
    var toggle = view.menuCategoryToggler
    var toggleIcon = view.toggleImg
    var icon = view.menuCatDealLogo
    var parent = view
}
```

Comment: post the code of the activity where you create the adapter instance so we can help in a better way

Comment: This is the code ```    class MenuViewHolder(val view: View, val context: Context, var restaurantPageFragment: RestaurantPage): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        var restaurant = restaurantPageFragment.restaurant
        var menuCat: RecyclerView? = null

        fun view() {
            menuCat = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.menuCat)
            menuCat!!.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            menuCat!!.adapter = RestaurantMenuAdapter(restaurant.Menus, context)
            
        }
    }```